# how do I get a particular text using Python

Tags: python, text-extraction

I need a text after a keyword

My text file like this. I am trying to extract the car info, car model, and append in to the python dict.

```
# car name 
BMW
suzuki

# car model 
X1 
TT

# color
red 
blue
```

My code:

```py
keywords = [car_name,car_model,color]
parsed_content = {}

def car_info(text):
    content = {}
    indices = []
    keys = []
    for key in Keywords:
        try:
            content[key] = text[text.index(key) + len(key):]
            indices.append(text.index(key))
            keys.append(key)
        except:
            pass         
    zipped_lists = zip(indices, keys)
    sorted_pairs = sorted(zipped_lists)
    # sorted_pairs

    tuples = zip(*sorted_pairs)
    indices, keys = [ list(tuple) for tuple in  tuples]
    # return keys
    print(keys)

    content = []
    for idx in range(len(indices)):
        if idx != len(indices)-1:
            content.append(text[indices[idx]: indices[idx+1]])
        else:
            content.append(text[indices[idx]: ])
        
    for i in range(len(indices)):
        parsed_content[keys[i]] = content[i]   
    return parsed_content
```

my output is

```
parsed_content = {car_name : car_name BMW SUZUKI,
car_model : car_model x1 tt,
color : color red blue

 }
```

Expected output:

```
{'car_name': ['bmw', 'suzuki'],
 'car_model': ['x1', 'TT'],
 'color': ['red', 'blue']
}
```

Comment: Your formatting was pretty messed up, I tried to clean it but I obviously had to guess some things. In particular, the expected output is now what makes sense, not what you originally wrote.

Comment: `keywords = [car_name,car_model,color]` is not valid Python unless those symbols are defined earlier in your code.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are doing here but why are you not using `open` and `readlines` to extract the text?

More info [here...](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-read-text-file/)

Once you have extracted the data you need you can build any data structure you wish

Comment: I am trying to get that text after a keyword in that case I have paragraphs also so how can I extract that particular text or paragraph after that keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using index

```
txt = '''# car name 
BMW
suzuki

# car model 
X1 
TT

# color
red 
blue'''

txt_split = [i.strip() for i in txt.split('\n') if i.strip()]
header_list = ['# car name', '# car model', '# color']
headers = [txt_split.index(i) for i in txt_split if i in header_list]
for i in range(len(headers)):
    values = txt_split[headers[i]].partition('#')[2].strip().replace(' ', '_')
    if i == len(headers) - 1:
        keys = txt_split[headers[i] + 1:]
    else:
        keys = txt_split[headers[i] + 1:headers[i + 1]]
    print({values: keys})

    >>>> {'car_name': ['BMW', 'suzuki']}
    >>>> {'car_model': ['X1', 'TT']}
    >>>> {'color': ['red', 'blue']}
```

Comment: if # is not in the text can we find it from the keyword

Comment: yes you can use the keywords.

Comment: how we can find it I used some diff scenarios but I am stuck on that point

Comment: what are characteristics of your keywords? once you found the keywords in a text. you can extract the text between them

Comment: I define a list of keywords and according to that keyword we can  extract that text

Comment: @endpoints i have updated the code now you can pass the list of keywords and extract between those words

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt seems extraordinarily overcomplicated. Aren't you simply looking for something like this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

def car_info(filename):
    with open(filename) as lines:
        values = defaultdict(list)
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                continue
            elif line.startswith("# "):
                keyword = line[2:]
            else:
                values[keyword].append(line.rstrip('\n'))
    return values
```

Of course, the proper solution to your problem is to use a text format which Python already knows how to read. The data in YAML format could look like

```
---
items:
  car name:
  - BMW
  - Suzuki
  car model:
  - X1
  - TT
  color:
  - red
  - blue
```

though if the items are related by index, a representation which would make more sense would be

```
---
cars:
  car:
  - name: BMW
  - model: X1
  - color: red
 car:
  - name: Suzuki
  - model: TT
  - color: blue
```

Comment: I like this approach you could also add further conditions for the key words and have further refinement to the structure of the outputted dict.

Comment: if we have any other documents file so can we define the specific keyword and get text after that keywords

Comment: Sure you can, but the YAML format suggestion still seems to be a much better solution to what you seem to be asking.